# 2D array NullPointerException

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to store a value in a 2D array:

```java
int length = red[0].length;
int[][] sums = new int[length][];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        int val = red[i][j];
        total = val + total;
    }
    sums[0][i] = total;
}
```

It works fine is I store `total` in a 1D array. Can anyone tell me why it's giving me this error?

Comment: *int length = red[0].length;*
*for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {*
I recall my point, you would get IndexOutOfBoundsException if the problem was related to nested arrays not having the same length this is the problem. If it is NullPointerException it is probably that some of the nested arrays are not initialized. We don't have the code to confirm how *red* is initialized.

Comment: You are trying to access `sum[0][i]` before it is initialising it due to which you get the `NullPointerException`. Either change your array declaration to include length of the columns like `int [][] sums = new int[length][length]` or initialise each row manually before accessing it like `sums[i] = new int[length];`. I have used `length` here but you can use anything else as well.

Comment: sums array is actually an array with length rows and zero columns so trying to fetch any element results in NullPointerException.

Comment: Also you should indicate the Line that yields the NullPointerException. There's already 2 possibilities that can be spotted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive that inner array of sums should also have certain capacity. For example:

```java
int[][] sums = new int[length][length];
```

Otherwise you are accessing `sum[0][i]` but inner array can’t be accessed at index `i`.